# highcharts, after using the setData method in bar chart, legend works wierd

Tags: javascript, highcharts

After using the setData method, the legend of the first column of the bar chart applies to all columns.
And when you hide the other columns, then under them a column of the same color as the first.

```js
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 250,
  },
  tooltip: {
    valueSuffix: ''
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        color: '#fff',
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bolder',
          textShadow: false
        },
        formatter: function() {
          return this.y
        },
        inside: true,
        rotation: 0
      },
      pointWidth: 20,
      groupPadding: 0.5,
    }
  },
  navigation: {
    buttonOptions: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },

  title: {
    text: ''
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['bufer', 'parser', 'index', 'store']
  },
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    title: {
      text: 'data'
    },
    labels: {
      overflow: 'justify'
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'bufer',
    data: [{
      x: 0,
      y: 2000
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'parser',
    data: [{
      x: 1,
      y: 7455
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'index',
    data: [{
      x: 2,
      y: 6567
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'store',
    data: [{
      x: 3,
      y: 3543
    }]
  }]
});


// the button action
$('#button').click(function() {
  chart.series[0].setData([{
    name: 'bufer',
    x: 0,
    y: 2010
  }, {
    name: 'parser',
    x: 1,
    y: 7455
  }, {
    name: 'index',
    x: 2,
    y: 6567
  }, {
    name: 'store',
    x: 3,
    y: 3543
  }]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<button id='button'>set data</button>
```

Fiddle that demonstrates my issue

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pierre_Cardi/7wqrrd8h/2/)

Could someone help solve this issue?
I wonder, how can i made the bar chart with multiple series, so it legend duplicates the categories. And show/hide different columns?

Comment: It's because you only update data for first series.So your first series overlap others

Comment: @R.K.Saini is right, [see here for an example where each series is updated](https://jsfiddle.net/7wqrrd8h/3/), not a dynamic solution though.

Comment: Before setting a new data, each series had one point. After, your first series has four elements, and that is the reason why you are receiving a situation described by you. Also, if you want to update data, the better choice is using Point.update() function (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Point.update). Example: https://jsfiddle.net/2ma9wrb9/.

Comment: Thanks everybody. Your answers helped me a lot. Especially the d_paul's answer